# How can I query only IDs 3, 4, 5 and 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id,name
FROM categ
WHERE email_activated='1'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

but I only want to query for IDs 3, 4, 5 and 1.

How can I specify those IDs in the query?

Comment: Put the target IDs in a staging table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an IN clause

```
SELECT id, name
FROM categ
WHERE email_activated='1'
AND id IN (1, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in